# Remove rows with same name in different columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this table in R:

```
| Left align | Right align | Center align |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|   
| A          |      A      |     1.4     :|
| A          |      B      |     1.2     :|
| A          |      C      |     1.0     :|
```

I would like to remove the lines that present the same row in two first column (for example A and A row (|A|A| 1.4).

```
| Left align | Right align | Center align |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|   
| A          |      A      |     1.4     :|
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! We are **not** a code-writing service. Please take your time and read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) before asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

Does this help?

```
> df
  COL1 COL2 COL3
1    A    A  1.4
2    A    B  1.2
3    A    C  1.0

> df[which(df$COL1 != df$COL2),]

  COL1 COL2 COL3
2    A    B  1.2
3    A    C  1.0
```

Comment: No. It doesn't. I received this mensage: cor[which(cor$otu != cor$env),]
Error in Ops.factor(cor$otu, cor$env) : 
  level sets of factors are different

Comment: You might want to change the type of first  two columns to `character` before running the `which` statement. It should work after that.
In this case: `df$COL1 <- as.character(df$COL1)` and same for the `COL2`